# ListView OnScroll event executing multiple times for same position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using listview to display comments. For that, i am implementing lazy listview loading as it may be possible that there are 50 comments in database. so i am rendering comments partially.

For testing i am right now making request for 3 comments. When i reached to 3rd row, i am again requesting for next 3 comments. Now problem is when i scrolled to 3rd row, Onscroll executing multiple times for 3rd row resulting multiple request to server instead of one time next 3 comments request.

Below is the code:

```
@Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        Log("isFirtTime - "+firstTimeLoaded+" ** noMore -"+ noMoreCommentsFound);
        if(firstTimeLoaded==false && noMoreCommentsFound==false) {
            Log("firstVisibleItem - "+firstVisibleItem+" ** visibleItemCount -"+ visibleItemCount+" ** totalItemCount"+totalItemCount);
            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount==totalItemCount) {
                if(FviewsAPI.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                    commentStartIndex+=3;                   
                    FviewsAPI.getMovieComments(movieId, commentStartIndex, commentEndIndex, MovieDetails.this);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

Below is the LogCat Details to track the scrolling events:

```
11-19 12:21:21.842: V/FVIEWS(10358): isFirtTime - false ** noMore -false
11-19 12:21:21.842: V/FVIEWS(10358): firstVisibleItem - 0 ** visibleItemCount - 2 ** totalItemCount - 3
11-19 12:21:21.862: V/FVIEWS(10358): pos : 2

11-19 12:21:21.872: V/FVIEWS(10358): isFirtTime - false ** noMore -false
11-19 12:21:21.872: V/FVIEWS(10358): firstVisibleItem - 0 ** visibleItemCount - 3 ** totalItemCount - 3
11-19 12:21:21.872: V/URL(10358): ~~URL - http://***.***.*.100/dipen/****_new/web/viewAllComments/14/3/3

11-19 12:21:21.882: V/FVIEWS(10358): isFirtTime - false ** noMore -false
11-19 12:21:21.882: V/FVIEWS(10358): firstVisibleItem - 0 ** visibleItemCount - 3 ** totalItemCount - 3
11-19 12:21:21.882: V/URL(10358): ~~URL - http://***.***.*.100/dipen/****_new/web/viewAllComments/14/6/3

11-19 12:21:21.892: V/FVIEWS(10358): isFirtTime - false ** noMore -false
11-19 12:21:21.892: V/FVIEWS(10358): firstVisibleItem - 0 ** visibleItemCount - 3 ** totalItemCount - 3
11-19 12:21:21.892: V/URL(10358): ~~URL - http://***.***.*.100/dipen/****_new/web/viewAllComments/14/9/3
```

If you see the logcat details, when 3rd row appear on screen, onScroll event logging the "visibleItemCount - 3" multiple times **( WIDTH OF THE LISTVIEW SET TO ONLY DISPLAY TWO ROWS ON SCREEN )** hence, it is calling multiple times the comment api intsead of only one time next 3 comments api.

***WHAT ANDROID DOC SAYS IS "onscroll event will be called after the scroll has completed"***  here is the link of doc : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll(android.widget.AbsListView, int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Then Why multiple times it is calling for 3rd row?? any Idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onscroll event will be called after the scroll has completed
```

Which means `onscroll event will be called after the last item of listview comes to visible`. I hope this help you.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I got it what doc is saying. But my question is, when i scroll down to 3rd row that means 3rd row will appear on screen. During this process, for 3rd row, it is calling multiple times onScroll event. you can see my logcat also for 3rd row. it suppose to call only one time after scroll is completed. why it is not happening?? hope you will get what i am trying to say.

Comment: Do you have fourth row? If not this is only happening. Why because `onscroll event will be called after the scroll has completed`, explaination : Scroll listener will check the listview repeatedly whether the last item comes to visible, and find that `yes` an every checking, so `onscroll` called for every checking.

Comment: Gunaseelan: thanks for your comment on this. forth row will appear after calling api for next 3 records. so, once i am on 3rd row, it will call api and after getting data from server, i am calling notifyDatasetchange on adapter. So, by following this approach, it should be call api only one time for 3rd row appearing on screen while in here my program, it is calling multiple times once i am first time scrolling to 3rd row.

Comment: Yes, This is the problem with `onscroll`. Now you have to use one boolean variable. Set it as false on inside `onscroll` (while calling api), and after getting data from server set that boolean variable as `true`, and in `onscroll` put that codes inside `if(boolean_variable)` condition.(whole code will run only if this boolean variable true only even onscroll called multiple times.) I hope you understood.

Comment: thanks. i got your point. But by this approach, i need multiple boolean variables. Because lets say i m calling api for every 5th position. so i need to track boolean variable for each 5th position if it is calling first time respectively. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No man, You can do with a single boolean variable. In onscroll(inside if condition) declare it as false, Once you declare it as false even onscroll gets called multiple times your if condition did not invoked, so these codes will run only one time. And then finally declare it as true at where you can( best after parsing all data).

Comment: Gunaseelan: very simple and clever solution. thanks a lot. :) i need to sharp my mind on this types of problems. :D  . Again thanks a lot.

Comment: Gunaseelan: thanks a lot. now its working awesome :D